# Postgresql connection issues from mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a postgres server from a mac. I keep getting this error and I am not sure what to do

This is the script I am using to connect to the database.

```
    ~/
     psql "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=~/downloads/server-ca.pem 
     sslcert=~/downloads/client-cert.pem sslkey=~/downloads/client-key.pem 
    hostaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 
    host=datatrain-170316:training 
    port=5432 
    user=rmanth dbname=training"
```

This is the error I am getting. Where am I going wrong?

> psql: missing "=" after "?" in connection info string

Comment: try `unalias -a` and then `psql` and please show the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use the tilde (`~`), try absolute path names.
- Remove the `:training` from `host`.
- Remove the `hostaddr` parameter if you want `verify-full`.

Then try again and see if it works (or if you get a different error message).